# partitioning table based on year and quarter

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I am trying to create a table partition in sql server 2016. I basically need to partition based on the year and quarter. We have two fields in the query that determine that. periodenddate which determines year and fiscalquarter which determines the quarter and is int field.
The second thing that I need is that partion should be created from the year 2000 to 2070
I have created 5 filegroups. So not sure how to allocate the partions across the filegroups

Please see my exisiting partition query below. It is currently partioning only by the year and considering last 5 years.

```
USE CoreReferenceStaging;  
GO  
-- Adds five new filegroups to the CoreReferenceStaging database  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging  
ADD FILEGROUP CT1;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging  
ADD FILEGROUP CT2;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging  
ADD FILEGROUP CT3;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging  
ADD FILEGROUP CT4;
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging  
ADD FILEGROUP CT5;


-- Adds one file for each filegroup.  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = ctdata1,  
    FILENAME = 'M:\Data\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ctdata1.ndf',  
    SIZE = 25MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 500MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 10MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP CT1;  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = ctdata2,  
    FILENAME = 'M:\Data\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ctdata2.ndf',  
    SIZE = 25MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 500MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 10MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP CT2;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = ctdata3,  
    FILENAME = 'M:\Data\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ctdata3.ndf',  
    SIZE = 25MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 500MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 10MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP CT3;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = ctdata4,  
    FILENAME = 'M:\Data\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ctdata4.ndf',  
    SIZE = 25MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 500MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 10MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP CT4;  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE CoreReferenceStaging   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = ctdata5,  
    FILENAME = 'M:\Data\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ctdata5.ndf',  
    SIZE = 25MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 500MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 10MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP CT5;  
GO  






CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition (datetime)  
    AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ();

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange  
    AS PARTITION financialStatementPartition  
    ALL TO ([PRIMARY]); 
DECLARE @periodenddate datetime = DATEADD(year, -4, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, '', GETDATE()), ''));
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
    NEXT USED CT1;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
    SPLIT RANGE(@periodenddate);
SET @periodenddate = DATEADD(year, 1, @periodenddate);
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
    NEXT USED CT2;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
    SPLIT RANGE(@periodenddate);
SET @periodenddate = DATEADD(year, 1, @periodenddate);
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
    NEXT USED CT3;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
    SPLIT RANGE(@periodenddate);
SET @periodenddate = DATEADD(year, 1, @periodenddate);
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
    NEXT USED CT4;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
    SPLIT RANGE(@periodenddate);
SET @periodenddate = DATEADD(year, 1, @periodenddate);
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
    NEXT USED CT5;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
    SPLIT RANGE(@periodenddate);




CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FinancialStatementIds_Partitioned](
    [financialCollectionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [companyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dataItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dataItemName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [dataItemvalue] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [unittypevalue] [int] NULL,
    [fiscalyear] [int] NULL,
    [fiscalquarter] [int] NULL,
    [periodenddate] [datetime] NULL,
    [filingdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [restatementtypename] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [latestforfinancialperiodflag] [bit] NULL,
    [latestfilingforinstanceflag] [bit] NULL,
    [currencyconversionflag] [int] NULL,
    [currencyname] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [periodtypename] [varchar](200) NULL
) ON financialStatementRange(periodenddate);
GO 

INSERT INTO dbo.FinancialStatementIds_Partitioned
SELECT *
FROM dbo.FinancialStatementIds WITH(TABLOCKX);
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.FinancialStatementIds;
GO
EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.FinancialStatementIds_Partitioned', N'FinancialStatementIds';
GO
```

Partition by year from 2000 to 2070

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange  
    AS PARTITION financialStatementPartition  
    ALL TO ([PRIMARY]); 

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20000101'
DECLARE @periodenddate DATE = '20700101'

while( @StartDate < @periodenddate) 
begin
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME financialStatementRange
    NEXT USED [PRIMARY];
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION financialStatementPartition()
    SPLIT RANGE(@StartDate);
   SET @StartDate = DATEADD(year, 1, @StartDate);

end
```

Comment: I have managed to alter the scheme to partition the table from 2000 to 2070 but need to partition by year and quarter. Updated the post

Comment: What do you hope to gain by the partitioning?

Comment: Quicker turnaround time for queries on partions

Comment: Please provide an example of them being faster; I have not seen such.  (Or at least not a case that could be countered by a suitable index on the non-partitioned table.)

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it may work for you:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Orders
(
    OrderID     integer NOT NULL,
    Name        nvarchar(20) NULL,
    OrderDate   date NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK__Orders_OrderID
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
            (OrderID)
        ON [PRIMARY]
)
ON PS (OrderDate);
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CX__Orders_OrderDate
ON dbo.Orders (OrderDate)
ON PS (OrderDate)
```